# Вывод даты. PostgreSQL+Node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

работаю в node.js и вывожу данные с PostgreSQL. Хочу вывести дату в формате YYYY-MM-DD, а мне выдает 'Thu May 23 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)'.
Тип моих полей - это DATE

Вот пример как я работаю

```
client.query("select name,surename,patronymic,title,start_date,expiration_date from my_membership where phone =$1",[log], function(err, result) {
 done()
```

В переменных: start_date и expiration_date, я вывожу дату.

Comment: `to_char(expiration_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD')` и `to_char(start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: @Suvitruf Это в postgres или в node.js сразу  исп

Comment: Прям в запросе замените.

Comment: @Suvitruf Перестает вообще выводить дату.

Comment: А у вас там точно тип дата на столбце?

Comment: @Suvitruf `start_date date NOT NULL,
  expiration_date date NOT NULL`